# problems with lz4 between php and golang

Tags: php, go, lz4

I try to compress data with lz4_compress in php and uncompress data with https://github.com/pierrec/lz4 in golang

but it fails.

it seems that the lz4_compress output misses the lz4 header, and the block data is little different.

please help me solve the problem.

```
<?php
echo base64_encode(lz4_compress("Hello World!"));
?>
```

output:

DAAAAMBIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCE=

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pierrec/lz4"
)

func main() {
    a, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("DAAAAMBIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCE=")
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", a)

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w := lz4.NewWriter(buf)
    b := bytes.NewReader([]byte("Hello World!"))
    w.ReadFrom(b)
    fmt.Printf("%b\n", buf.Bytes())
}
```

output:

[1100 0 0 0 11000000 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 100001]

[100 100010 1001101 11000 1100100 1110000 10111001 1100 0 0 10000000 1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100 1100100 100001]

Comment: This seems to be solely a php problem, the Go output looks correct.

Comment: The PHP extension [is just a thin wrapper around the C library](https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4/blob/master/lz4.c#L145) and looks unsuspicious at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

[lz4.h](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/master/lib/lz4.h) explicitly says

> lz4.h provides block compression functions. It gives full buffer control to user.
>
> Decompressing an lz4-compressed block also requires metadata (such as compressed size). Each application is free to encode such metadata in whichever way it wants.
>
> An additional format, called LZ4 frame specification (doc/lz4_Frame_format.md),
>     take care of encoding standard metadata alongside LZ4-compressed blocks. If your application requires interoperability, it's recommended to use it. A library is provided to take care of it, see lz4frame.h.

The PHP extension doesn't do that; [it produces bare compressed blocks](https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-lz4/blob/5b2e225f7ec6b7fb3c0778db137beb2891d5051e/lz4.c#L195).

http://lz4.github.io/lz4/ explicitly lists the PHP extension as not interoperable (in the "Customs LZ4 ports and bindings" section).

Answer (score 0):

Sound good! And now try

```
echo -n DAAAAMBIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCE= | base64 -d
```

I got in first 4 bytes is written 0C 00 00 00 - that is the lenght of string and rest is *Hello World!*. Therefore I think, that if php realize that compression of such a short input is not possible it writes the input (try `echo -n "Hello World!" | lz4c` ). But problem is it does not allow you recognize such a thing, or I'm wrong?